# const and not const in copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

When I wrote my copy constructor that: (HocSinh is a class)

```
HocSinh::HocSinh(HocSinh &a)
{
    hoTen = a.hoTen;
    diemVan = a.diemVan;
    diemToan = a.diemToan;
}
```

then:

```
HocSinh hocSinh("abc", 1, 2);
vector <HocSinh> dsHSCanTim;
dsHSCanTim.push_back(hocSinh);
```

I got an error: "no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'".
But when I wrote:

```
HocSinh::HocSinh(const HocSinh &a)
{
    hoTen = a.hoTen;
    diemVan = a.diemVan;
    diemToan = a.diemToan;
}
```

There was no error. 
Can someone explain this for me please. Thank everyone and sorry if my English is so bad.

Comment: If `HocSinh` is name of your class how come you're doing `dsHSCanTim.push_back(HocSinh);` ? `push_back` needs a object of `HocSinh`

Comment: In general, copy ctors should take its parameter by const reference unless there's a compelling reason for it to be non-const.

Comment: Sorry, it was: `HocSinh hocSinh("abc", 1, 2);` and push_back(hocSinh).

Comment: In general you should use `const` wherever it is possible to do so. Your copy constructor does not modify its argument, so it _can_ be `const`, therefore it _should_ be `const`. That ensures that it can accept both const and non-const objects.

Answer (score 4):

Because `std::vector::push_back` is defined as

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
void push_back (value_type&& val);
```

For an lvalue like `hocSinh`, the `std::vector::push_back` template would use the first one. Inside `std::vector::push_back` implementation, a copy constructor is used to construct the object in the memory segment allocated by `std::vector`. The implementation has to use `const value_type& val` as the source of this copy, so it needs a copy constructor with a `const` signature to take `val`.

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* a copy constructor with a const lvalue reference parameter is needed.

Comment: @juanchopanza OP asked why there should be `const`, and it is obvious if you want to use `val` as a function argument in the implementation of `void push_back (const value_type& val);`, the function has to assume a `const` parameter.

Comment: This is not completely obvious. A short explanation could make the answer better.